# Append input to list as integers

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, vector

If a user inputs three numbers separated by a space, how can I append them to a list as integers?

For example:

```
Enter vector A:
1 3 2
Enter vector B:
2 3 0
```

I'm sure str.split is required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
>>> input_one = "1 3 2"
>>> input_two = "2 3 0"
```

Convert to a list of strings using [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> vector_a = input_one.split()
>>> vector_b = input_two.split()
```

Post process the lists to make each element of the list an `int`. [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) gets rid of any extraneous spaces in the string.

```
>>> vector_a = [int(a.strip()) for a in vector_a]
>>> vector_b = [int(a.strip()) for a in vector_b]
```

This gives you:

```
>>> vector_a
[1, 3, 2]
>>> vector_b
[2, 3, 0]
```

Comment: @user3481556 Could you please accept the answer if it helped resolve your issue? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. I've been trying to, but it keeps telling me to wait a few minutes.